# How to decrease running time of this particular solution?

Tags: python, performance, time

I am trying to write a piece of code that will generate a permutation, or some series of characters that are all different in a recursive fashion.

```
def getSteps(length, res=[]):
    if length == 1: 
        if res == []:
            res.append("l")
            res.append("r")
            return res
        else:
            for i in range(0,len(res)):
                res.append(res[i] + "l")
                res.append(res[i] + "r")
            print(res)
            return res
    else:
        if res == []:
            res.append("l")
            res.append("r")
            return getSteps(length-1,res)
        else:
            for i in range(0,len(res)):
                res.append(res[i] + "l")
                res.append(res[i] + "r")
            print(res)
            return getSteps(length-1,res)

def sanitize(length, res):
    return [i for i in res if len(str(i)) == length]

print(sanitize(2,getSteps(2)))
```

So this would return

"LL", "LR", "RR, "RL" or some permutation of the series.

I can see right off the bat that this function probably runs quite slowly, seeing as I have to loop through an entire array. I tried to make the process as efficient as I could, but this is as far as I can get. I know that some unnecessary things happen during the run, but I don't know how to make it much better. So my question is this: what would I do to increase the efficiency and decrease the running time of this code?

edit = I want to be able to port this code to java or some other language in order to understand the concept of recursion rather than use external libraries and have my problem solved without understanding it.

Comment: does the standard library provide you with any tools you could fully leverage, or build a solution off of? http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: One thing which would improve performance slightly would be to change the "if res == []" to "if not res", since empty lists evaluate to False in Python.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I want the solution to be recursive, as I am attempting to code up a sort of "proof of concept" for recursion in this piece of code. Also, I want to be able to port this to java, or c++ to really understand the concept more than the syntax.

Comment: what is `getSteps` _supposed_ to do in the general case? Do you want one permutation or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to combine the binary approach and a recursive approach?

Yes, and @gribbler came **very** close to that in the post to which that comment was attached.  He just put the pieces together in "the other order".

How can you construct all the bitstrings of length `n`, in increasing order (when viewed as binary integers)?  Well, if you already have all the bitstrings of length `n-1`, you can prefix them all with `0`, and then prefix them all again with `1`.  It's that easy.

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [""]
    return [a + b for a in "RL" for b in f(n-1)]

print(f(3))
```

prints

```
['RRR', 'RRL', 'RLR', 'RLL', 'LRR', 'LRL', 'LLR', 'LLL']
```

Replace `R` with `0`, and `L` with `1`, and you have the 8 binary integers from 0 through 7 in increasing order.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution I was looking for. I wanted to do that approach initially, which is prefix the results with zero, but my method was a bit too redundant. This gets the job done quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Your design is broken. If you call `getSteps` again, `res` won't be an empty list, it will have garbage left over from the last call in it.

I think you want to generate permutations recursively, but I don't understand where you are going with the `getSteps` function

Here is a simple recursive function

```
def fn(x):
    if x==1:
        return 'LR'
    return [j+i for i in fn(x-1) for j in "LR"]
```

Comment: I think that's what my objective is. If I call some function fn(x), for some number lets pick 3, fn(3) should return "LLL", "LLR", "LRL", "LRR, "RRR", "RRL", "RLR", "RLL"

Comment: If you only have 2 values it's much easier. Imagine replacing `L=0`, `R=1` now it just looks like binary numbers from 0-7

Comment: That's true. I understood that shortly after coding this, but I couldn't find out how to recursively solve the problem. Is there a way to combine the binary approach and a recursive approach?

Comment: Why would you use a recursive approach? It won't be more efficient

Comment: That's true, but I want to make it as efficient as possible while still using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into itertools. There is a function there called `permutations` which does exactly what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Actually "permutations" isn't the right word. `itertools.product` is the correct tool. `map(''.join, product('LR', repeat=n))`